# Javascript - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined, code-injection

Could someone explain to me why I get the "Property of value is undefined error" please? My Javascript Skills are very limited. Trying to do Communication between two scripts.

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {value: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.value);
});
```

Should communicate with:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.value == "hello")
      sendResponse({value: "goodbye"});
});
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Goodbye and thanks in advance

Comment: Unless "request" is an object containing a "value" tag, that's not the right way to get the value.  You should just be able to say 'if(request=="hello")'

Comment: I changed it, but if I type `sendResponse("goodbye")` and I print response, it is still undefined,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in the code, "response" is undefined, so it has no property named "value" (from response.value).  So you should probably check if response is undefined before printing it to the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) But If I check if it is undefined before printing it, and it is undefined, then it won't print, right? So why is it undefined and how can I print it?

Comment: I answered that it cannot read a property of an undefined value.  There is nothing to print other than 'undefined'.  You're now asking why your script doesn't work, in which case you need to ask a new question with more details/code.

Comment: From that point of view, You helped me avoiding my error, which is some kind of progress. Thank you. But I asked how to fix my problem. The above code is  everything I have, the first part in a background.js of a chrome extension, the second in content.js.