# TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFields' of undefined reactjs & django? how can i resolve this issue without antd?

Tags: reactjs

when i try to login then i get this error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFields' of undefined), i also read the documentation about antd but i don't want to use antd in my project how can i resolve this issue without antd... i have simple react-bootstrap Form... anybody know how can i solve this issue?

login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as actions from './actions/auth';
import FullPageLoader from "../components/FullPageLoader";

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        let errorMessage = null;
        if (this.props.error) {
            errorMessage = (
                <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="form-flex">
                {errorMessage}
                {
                    this.props.isLoading ?
                        <FullPageLoader />
                        :
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form form-group">
                            <h1 className="h4 text-center font-weight-normal">Sign in</h1>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="username"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    type="text"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="username" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="password"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    type="password"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="password" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-block btn-secondary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            <small>
                                <Link to="/passwordforget">Forgot password?</Link>
                            </small>
                        </Form>
                }
            </div >
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NormalLoginForm);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637673/javascript-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot read property 'validateFields' of undefined` is being caused by the code `this.props.form.validateFields`. You are not passing a `form` prop into the component so it is `undefined`, and throwing that error.

Either define a validator somewhere and use it, or remove that line.

Comment: how can i pass this form prop in component?

Comment: how can i use it without validator... would you like to define it for me....?

Comment: I'm guessing you copy-pasted some code and that's why it's not working?
Look at the code you copied, and see where the component is called from, and see what `form` it is given, and try to get the `validateFields` from that, but I suspect it's another library, so you could just write a validator yourself.

Comment: Some Form libraries will do some nice validation stuff for you, with text highlighting and the such. This may be a check that it has finished that. Otherwise, you can just define some simple checks to make sure the info is valid and non-empty before handling the submit.

Comment: here is the original code i have copy and paste [github](https://github.com/justdjango/DjReact/blob/master/src/containers/Login.js)

Comment: Yeh so they're using antd. Maybe find and copy some code from somewhere else that isn't using antd if you don't want to use it. How you set up a form varies a lot depending on what tools you have decided to use.